# reinterpret cast an array from string to int

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

I'd like to reinterpret a string in a array of int where every int take charge of 4 or 8 chars based on processor architecture.

Is there a way to achieve this in a relatively inexpensive way?
I tried out this but doesn't seem to reinterpret 4 chars in one int

```
string text = "abcdabcdefghefgh";

unsafe
{
    fixed( char* charPointer = text )
    {
        Int32* intPointer = (Int32*)charPointer;

        for( int index = 0; index < text.Length / 4; index++ )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( intPointer[ index ] );
        }
    }
}
```

SOLUTION: (change Int64 or Int32 based on your needs)

```
string text = "abcdabcdefghefgh";

unsafe
{
    fixed( char* charPointer = text )
    {
            Int64* intPointer = (Int64*)charPointer;
            int conversionFactor = sizeof( Int64 ) / sizeof( char );

            int index = 0;
            for(index = 0; index < text.Length / conversionFactor; index++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( intPointer[ index ] );
            }

            if( text.Length % conversionFactor != 0 )
            {
                intPointer[ index ] <<= sizeof( Int64 );
                intPointer[ index ] >>= sizeof( Int64 );

                Console.WriteLine( intPointer[ index ] );
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Chars in C# are 2 bytes, so with an Int32 pointer you're going to get two chars per int.

Comment: If you know your characters are 8-bit friendly you could extract them and stuff four into each integer yourself, but you would need to make a copy of the data.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair please mess somewhere else.. I want my title to be expressive of the problem so google can help

Comment: @sam Please follow my link: *Stack Overflow is optimized so that tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of the question.* ... and watch your tongue!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair that is not an excuse to write meaningless titles. OK we have tags and they work.. and so what? Do you name you variables a1 a2 a3 just because the compiler compile it?

Comment: @sam Removing *C#* from your title doesn't make your title meaningless. This is going to end in a pointless discussion, you may want to participate on the meta-discussion!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I'd like to have C# on my title but i'm not gonna fight. From google i don't visit links i'm not sure apply to my situation, even if it is pertinent becaue of tag optimizations. Bye

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it right. `sizeof(char) == 2 && sizeof(int) == 4`. The loop conversion factor must be 2, not 4. It's `sizeof(int) / sizeof(char)`. If you like this style you can use this exact expression. `sizeof` is a little known C# feature.

Note, that right now you lose the last character if the length is not even.

About performance: The way you have done it is as inexpensive as it gets.